# BeautifulSoup4 can't extract only text from a tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract title, description and url from every item in 
an xml file, but I am having trouble to extract the text of the description
tag without the tags inside it.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def read_xml(url):
"""reads xml string from url"""

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as source:
        html=source.read()

    return BeautifulSoup(html,'xml')

def read_content(html_file):
    """reads title,description and url from xml file"""

    content={'title':[],'description':[],'url':[]}

    item_lines=html_file.find_all('item')


    #item_lines is a list of the content within <item></item> tags
    for item in item_lines:
        content['title'].append(item.title.string)
        content['description'].append(item.description.text[:50]+"..")
        content['url'].append(item.link.text)

    return content

soup=read_xml('https://www.gamespot.com/feeds/game-news/')

content=read_content(soup)

for content in display_content.values():
    print(content)
    print("\n")
```

And this is the output (only showing the first elements of the lists):

```
['Fortnite Guide: Week 2 Secret Battle Banner Location (Season 6 Hunting Party Challenge)', 'Getting Away With Crime In Red Dead Redemption 2 Is Tricky', "This Is How Red Dead Redemption 2's Cores, Health, And Stats Work", "Red Dead Redemption 2: Here's How The Horses ...]

['<p>Season 6 of <a href="https://www.gamespot.com/f..', '<p><a href="https://www.gamespot.com/red-dead-rede..', '<p>In terms of scale, scope, gameplay systems, and..', '<p>One of the key areas of <a href="https://www.ga..', '<p>Week 2 of <a href="https://www.gamespot.com/for..', '<p>Forza Horizon is back for another year, and tha..', '<p>From all that we\'ve seen of ...]


['https://www.gamespot.com/articles/fortnite-guide-week-2-secret-battle-banner-locatio/1100-6462272/', 'https://www.gamespot.com/articles/getting-away-with-crime-in-red-dead-redemption-2-i/1100-6462203/', 'https://www.gamespot.com/articles/this-is-how-red-dead-redemption-2s-cores-health-an/1100-6462201/', ...]
```

As you can see there are p and a tags in the second list, which I am not able to get rid off, I tried .get_text(), .string, .text, .descendants and tried finding a solution in the documentation, most of the time it is the same output. I also don't want to manually remove those tags, because the program should be applicable for any xml document.

I would really appreciate if you could help me in this matter or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the description is a html element just brew it as a soup with `BeautifulSoup` and extract text from it.

```
desc = BeautifulSoup(item.description.text, 'html.parser')
content['description'].append(desc.text[:50]+"..")
```

If you are feeling that as complicated you can use regular expressions to get rid of them. But i would not personally suggest it because your text may contain normal texts with the same pattern.

```
import re
desc = re.sub("(<.*?>)", "", str(item.description.text), 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
content['description'].append(desc.text[:50]+"..")
```

The `<.*?>` will select all the HTML tags and replace them with empty string.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Ah now I know why it didn't work. Thank you so much, everything is working!